# CustomProperties set by Office-JS Outlook addin not shared between OWA & Outlook client

Tags: javascript, office-js

I've got an Office JS based Outlook addin which I'm successfully using in OWA, and the Outlook thick client on Mac (and Windows, when I get a chance to fire up my Windows VM).

My addin sets some `CustomProperties` on Message items when I'm composing and then saves those properties for later use.

The code looks a lot like the samples in the Office-JS docs, but here's an abridged version for reference:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync((result: AsyncResult): void => {
    let customProperties = result.value;

    let oldValue = customProperties.get("foo);
    let newValue = Date.now();
    console.log("Old value = ", oldValue, ", setting to: ", newValue);

    customProperties.set("foo", newValue.toString());
    customProperties.saveAsync(() => {});
 });
```

However, it appears that the state of the `CustomProperties` is not shared between the addin running in OWA and the same addin running in Outlook.

Example:

Edit message in OWA, set the 'foo' `CustomProperty` to the current timestamp (let's call it "ts1").
If I close my OWA session, open the item again, I see that the `CustomProperty` is set to the expected value.

Now if I open the same message in Outlook, the "foo" `CustomProperty` is empty.

If I then cause the "foo" `CustomProperty` to be set from Outloook (let's call the new value "ts2"), and re-launch my addin within OWA, I still see the "foo" `CustomProperty` with the initial value I set in OWA, ie "ts1".

Nothing in the docs for `CustomProperties` implies that the values are siloed per-client in addition to being addin-specific.  Is this just a bug, or is the intention that the properties be private to addin/client pair?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to **Stack Overflow**, try adding some of your relevant code, then we can start helping you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, and we are working towards fixing it.

Comment: Thanks @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility.  Is this a Mac-specific bug, or am I going to see the same issue(s) between Windows/OWA as well?  Any idea of an ETA for a fix?